# Recover data from EXT3 filesystem

Tags: linux, ext3, rm

Our junior sysadmin accidently deleted some of the directories. Can anyone please suggest any free/proprietary application to recover files from an EXT3 filesystem (RHEL 5.x) ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I really hope you have already taken the affected partition offline so to prevent data been written on top of the deleted data.

One useful tool that has worked for me in the past is [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/).
Remount the affected partition as read only and then use extundelete to recover the data.

I suppose it is pointless to reiterate that prevention is always better than the cure. Keep daily backups at least.

Comment: +1 extra for the backups, if I could.  I don't understand why anyone neglects those.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/recovering-a-deleted-file-on-ext3-almost-there-441914/

Comment: We really do prefer that answers have content, not pointers to content. This may theoretically answer the question however, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/). We tried it before. It is a great tool!